# Center–align arabic text

Tags: typography, text, alignment, arabic

Is it acceptable to center–align Arabic text and if so, is there anything I should take care of in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Arabic but I don't see why it wouldn't be acceptable. it is just read from right to left but you can still center-align it.

example:

[image]